# Apex. How to refresh the URL of Display Image item?

Tags: oracle-apex

I cannot find any documentation.

I have a Display Image item in Apex. It is configured to take the URL from "Image URL stored in Page Item Value"

The URL is loaded from a table with a SQL query.

But I need to change the URL, and display the new image.

I change the URL with a "Set Value" dynamic event fired from another item, but it does not changes anything on the Display Image item.

I checked that the Set Value items works when updating a display only item, but the exact same procedure  does not works with the Display Image item.

I also tried to fire a "refresh" dynamic event, but it does nothing.

I'm going crazy trying to find the documentation, but it is shallow, and does not gives any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way. Instead of a "Set value" Dynamic action, it should be a "Execute JavaScript Code" Dynamic action, with this code:

```
    $("#DISPLAY_IMAGE_ITEM").attr('src','https://someURL');
```

Note: if the URL is taken from an Item value, it should be assured that the item has escape characters  disabled.

Comment: The Display Image component seems not to support the DA's Refresh action. Need use JS codes to modify the src attribute of the image.